# Find all greatest common divisors over $\mathbb{C}$ of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Find all greatest common divisors over $\mathbb{C}$ of the two polynomials $x^6+2x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2+4x+3$ and $x^5+3x^4+2x^3-2x-1$.

Which are the greatest common divisors over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Euclidean algorithm...?

Comment: @wednesdaymiko: The Euclidean algorithm will give the same result for any field containing the coefficients, hence in this case, any field containing $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: the result should be $$x^2+x+1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Euclidean algorithm, this is what I got.

$f=x^6+2x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2+4x+3$

$g=x^5+3x^4+2x^3-2x-1$

$$x^6+2x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2+4x+3 = (x^5+3x^4+2x^3-2x-1)(x-1) + (x^3+3x^2+3x+2)$$
$$(x^5+3x^4+2x^3-2x-1) = (x^3+3x^2+3x+2)(x^2-1) + (x^2+x+1)$$
$$x^3+3x^2+3x+2 = (x^2+x+1)(x+2)$$

$gcd(f, g) = x^2+x+1$